# How do I place main element above header and below nav element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I tried to position the main element above the header and below the nav element, I used the z-index but it doesn't work properly.

I use position sticky in header and position relative in main element because some stuff uses position absolute.

Do you have any solution for my case?

```css
header,
nav,
main {width: 100%;}
header{
  height: 10rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav {
  height: 4rem;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
}
main {
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  background: crimson;
  z-index: 2;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>navbar</nav>
  header
</header>
<main>main</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-work your HTML so that it follows that order. If you want your nav element at the top and header at the bottom, don't nest the `nav` in the header.

```css
header,
nav,
main {width: 100%;}
header{
  height: 10rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: blueviolet;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav {
  height: 4rem;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
}
main {
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  background: crimson;
  z-index: 2;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>navbar</nav>
<main>main</main>
<header>header</header>
```

Comment: I still want to nest the nav inside the header element. Instead separate the header and nav I made a div element as an addition

Comment: @ShaefulAmin Also, `z-index` places elements on top or behind other elements by layer, not by order.